# One-to-one and one-to-many association to same domain class in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, associations, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have two domain classes -- `Account` and `Member`, and I am having trouble finding the correct combination of associations and `mappedBy` attributes to model their relationship. In plain English, an `Account` requires one and only one primary member. It also has 0 - many dependents. My initial attempt looked like:

Account.groovy

```
class Account {
    String displayId

    Member primaryMember
    SortedSet<Member> dependents = new TreeSet<Member>()

    static belongsTo = [Member]
    static hasMany = [dependents: Member]
}
```

Member.groovy

```
class Member implements Comparable<Member> {
    MemberType memberType = MemberType.PRIMARY
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static belongsTo = [account: Account]

    @Override
    int compareTo(Member m) {
        return (this.memberType <=> m?.memberType) * 100 + (this.lastName <=> m?.lastName) * 10 + (this.firstName <=> m?.firstName)
    }
}
```

This causes problems when I attempt to instantiate and persist the accounts and members. For example,

AccountIntegrationTests.groovy

```
class AccountIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    Account smiths
    Member john
    Member jane

    @Before
    void setup() {}

    @Test
    void testShouldLoadAccountWithNoDependents() {
        // Arrange
        smiths = new Account(displayId: "ABCDEFG")

        john = new Member(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", memberType: MemberType.PRIMARY)
        smiths.primaryMember = john
        smiths.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        def smithsId = smiths.id
        smiths.discard()

        // Act
        def loadedSmiths = Account.get(smithsId)

        // Assert
        assert loadedSmiths.members.size() == 1
        assert loadedSmiths.primaryMember == john
        assert loadedSmiths.dependents.size() == 0
    }

    @Test
    void testShouldLoadAccountWithOneDependent() {
        // Arrange
        smiths = new Account(displayId: "ABCDEFG")
        john = new Member(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", memberType: MemberType.PRIMARY)
        smiths.primaryMember = john
        smiths.addToDependents(new Member(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Smith", memberType: MemberType.DEPENDENT))
        smiths.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        john = smiths.primaryMember
        jane = smiths.dependents.first()
        def smithsId = smiths.id
        smiths.discard()

        // Act
        def loadedSmiths = Account.get(smithsId)

        // Assert
        assert loadedSmiths.members.size() == 2
        assert loadedSmiths.primaryMember.firstName == "john"
        assert loadedSmiths.dependents.size() == 1
        assert loadedSmiths.dependents.first().firstName == "jane"
    }
}
```

will throw exceptions because the database tables for the second test look like

Account

```
id | display_id
1  | ABCDEFG
```

Member

```
id | first_name | last_name | member_type | account_id
1  | John       | Smith     | Primary     | 1
2  | Jane       | Smith     | Dependent   | 1
```

Obviously I would like the account to retrieve John as the primary member, and Jane as the dependent, but when GORM tries to load account.primaryMember, it throws a Hibernate exception that there are multiple rows (in Member) matching the account ID (1). I need a `mappedBy` discriminator to distinguish between the two associations, but the versions I have tried did not work:

Account

```
static mappedBy = [primaryMember: 'primaryMember', dependents: 'dependents']
- or -
static mappedBy = [dependents: 'account']
```

I have read the GORM documentation for both the associations and [`mappedBy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) , as well as [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640996/grails-hasone-and-hasmany-same-domain) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647584/hibernate-mapping-onetomany-and-onetoone-on-child-object-property) on [the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536669/multiple-hasmany-relationships-to-same-domain-class-in-grails) regarding [multiple associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654277/multiple-associations-in-grails) to the [same model](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/possible-bug-with-hasOne-td3394999.html), unfortunately they all seem to be modeling multiple `hasMany` associations. The one that does reference both one-to-many and one-to-one relationships to the same model illustrates it as:

```
class Person {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [team: Team]
}

class Team {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [coach: Person]
    static hasMany = [players: Person]
}
```

However, I tried to use this simple implementation and got:

```
--Output from testShouldLoadAccountWithNoDependents--
| Failure:  testShouldLoadAccountWithNoDependents(AccountIntegrationTests)
|  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Account; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Account
    at AccountIntegrationTests.testShouldLoadAccountWithNoDependents(AccountIntegrationTests.groovy:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Account
    ... 1 more
```

`AccountIntegrationTests.groovy:26` is the line `smiths.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`. When I modified the `Team/Account` class to:

```
class Team {
    String name
    Person coach

    static hasMany = [players: Person]
}
```

I encountered the same exception, so I believe some kind of `cascade` is required. I tried adding a `cascade` to the `Account`:

Account

```
static mapping = {
    primaryMember cascade: 'all'
    dependents cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
}
```

then I also tried using event triggers:

Account

```
def beforeInsert() {
    if (primaryMember?.isDirty()) {
        primaryMember.save()
    }
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (primaryMember?.isDirty()) {
        primaryMember.save()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches resolved the `transient instance` exception. Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embarrassingly simple solution was to remove the `static belongsTo = [account: Account]` from `Member`. The bidirectional association was causing the issues.